# Query a sheet based on checkbox and order according to check order

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

In Google Sheets, I have two sheets that work together and I want to achieve the following:

- I have a sheet1 with information in rows and a checkbox at the beginning
- When the checkbox is checked, the information is imported into sheet2
- I want this sheet2 to be ordered according to the time the checkbox was checked

I use the following function in sheet 2 to retrieve information from sheet 1:

```
=QUERY(QUERY('SHEET1'!A2:Z1000), "where Col1 =TRUE", 1)
```

Now what happens, if I select rows, the ordering in sheet2 is similar to the ordering in sheet1.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Hi, welcome to WebApps. You are asking us to comment on the operation of a spreadsheet without supplying any details of the data in that spreadsheet. Your query is executed when the checkbox is checked, but you don't explain how/when the exact time of this event is captured, included in the data in sheet2 or accessible to be sorted. Would you please edit your question to include some sample data from sheet 1, an example of the data created on sheet2, and example of how you expect a successful sort would appear.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.